# Getting image out of database with PHP echo

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database in which there is a row containing the images. Now in my code, I want to get images out of the database, but somehow I am unable to do it. Following is my code – kindly help me out –:

```
<?php

$qry = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY products.id DESC LIMIT 0, 1", $con);
if (!$qry)
{
    die("Query Failed: ". mysql_error());
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($qry))
{
    echo "<h2>".$row['title']."</h2>";
    echo "<img src=".'Image/'.$row['image']." />";
    echo "<p>".substr($row['body'],0,200)."<a href=articles.php?id=".$row['id']." > Read more</a></p>";
    echo "<p>".$row['price']."</p>";
}

?>
```

If I don't use PHP and just use simply the `<img>` tag, then the path must be  `src="Image/passbook.jpg"` and it works fine but it's not working with PHP. I am creating an admin panel so that the client can delete or update the images as he want, so I must not use simple `<img>` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing,

```
echo "<img src=".'Image/'.$row['image']." />";
```

to

```
echo "<img src='Image/".$row['image']."' />";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have error in image declaration code. Correct it as below,

```
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($qry) )
{
    echo "<h2>".$row['title']."</h2>";
    echo "<img src = 'Image/".$row['image']."' alt = ""/>";
    echo "<p>".substr($row['body'],0,200)."<a href=articles.php?id=".$row['id']." > Read more</a></p>";
    echo "<p>".$row['price']."</p>";
}
```

Comment: Just curious. Why you always duplicating the answers ?

Comment: @Rikesh what do you mean brother..?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
echo "<img src='Image/".$row['image']."' />";
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($qry))
{
    $title = $row['title'];
    $src = $row['image'];
    $whatever = $row['body'];
    echo "$title <br/><img src="$src" alt="my fancy photo" height="" width=""/><br/>$watever";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this :

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($qry))
{
    echo "<h2>".$row['title']."</h2>";
    echo "<img src = 'Image/".$row['image']."' alt = ""/>";
    echo "<p>".substr($row['body'],0,200)."<a href=articles.php?id=".$row['id']." > Read more</a></p>";
    echo "<p>".$row['price']."</p>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use this

```
echo "<img src=Image/".$row['image']." />";
```